# Getting error You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubeconfig, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I am getting the following error when trying to use the kubectl command:-

**error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)**

i am using the eks and after successfully doing all the activity, i have created a serviceaccount having the cluster-admin role attached to it. and using the same i am trying to access the api-server.

**configuration-file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: default-cluster
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUN5RENDQWJDZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpNQjRYRFRJd01URXdNakUwTkRVd01sb1hEVE13TVRBek1URTBORFV3TWxvd0ZURVRNQkVHQTFVRQpBeE1LYTNWaVpYSnVaWFJsY3pDQ0FTSXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRGdnRVBBRENDQVFvQ2dnRUJBTlp4Cm00amNBUFltdXF5NVpvVFNKSjFjUTdtc1NCN2lxai9WWFloTFVNNFZ3bGdjNDJ3WVVURnc2aHWi9oZVh3T3FiVElrWFllUmwKRm9OdHRkZWQ5QUtoU3VxY0didVBycWhsSGFKTWxhOVBXMmZGeC8xVFBlRk5BeEc4OGZhV01YUC9EMXNxb1MxaQpCSXEvM1ZtaU9rVy9GL1huMHNzTXh5bnNOYmZydFlpcDZURUxuZUdIMS9BZXd4c3pIUzNjdFFRQzVHST0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
    server: https://1A36198654FEEE06915E639FE356F7832.yl4.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com
contexts:
- name: default-context
  context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: default
    user: default-user
current-context: default-context
users:
- name: default-user
  user:
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJu
```

Not sure what is the issue, why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a key created by another account instead of the one created by the currently logged in user. Note the logged in user in the upper right corner of your page, using the key it created to configure aws again will solve your current problem.